# Conditional convergence of $\sum_k \frac{\epsilon_k}{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

Consider the infinite series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon_k}{k}, \quad \epsilon_k = 
\begin{cases} +1 \quad (n = 1 \; \text{or} \; n \; \text{prime})\\
-1 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
The series is clearly not absolutely convergent, and I suspect that it diverges. I am interested in proofs that settle the convergence question, from elementary to advanced.

*This question came up in my Calculus class today.*

Comment: Yes, intuitively, the primes are sparse (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), so most of the terms in the series are with $\epsilon_{k} = -1$, hence diverges to $-\infty$.  To converge, by contrast, the series would have to be close enough (in the number of +'s vs. -'s) to an alternating series, $\epsilon_{k} = (-1)^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could  use [Kronecker's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma) in the form that if the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^n {\epsilon_k\over k}$ converges, then ${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon_k\to 0$. This would imply, for the prime counting function $\pi(n)$, that ${\pi(n)\over n}\to {1\over 2}.$

But only two of every six consecutive integers can possibly be prime, so
${\pi(6n)\over 6n}\leq {1\over 3}$, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: This is a very nice approach as it relies on a nontrivial refinement of the elementary "divergence test".

Answer (score 3):

Through Euler's product for the $\zeta$ function
$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s} = \prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}\quad (s>1)\tag{1}$$
and logarithmic differentiation/summation by parts it can be proved that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\approx \log N,\qquad \sum_{p\leq N}\frac{1}{p}\approx \log\log N \tag{2} $$
hence the partial sums of your series diverge like $\log\log N-2\log N\to -\infty$.
Informally speaking, primes are not dense enough to counteract the divergence of the harmonic series. We may also directly apply summation by parts and exploit some weak form of the PNT to be able to state
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N}\epsilon_k \leq -N+\frac{C N}{\log(N)}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\epsilon_k}{k}\quad\text{diverges.}\tag{3} $$
As suggested in the comments (thanks to user1952009), the very crude bound $\pi(N)\leq\frac{N}{3}$ (for any $N$ large enough) is already enough to prove the divergence of $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\epsilon_k}{k}$ by summation by parts.

Comment: The OP wants to see a detailed and step by step solution so his students can understand

Comment: @DeepSea: in such a case their teacher can easily work out the details, with the help of Wikipedia, too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems.

Comment: Thank you for that argument, it actually connects to some concepts that are accessible to my students. As it is close to the Prime Number Theorem, it' s not exactly elementary :)

Comment: @HansEngler: a weak form of the PNT is enough to prove divergence. Chebyshev's bound $$\pi(N)\leq \frac{N\log 4}{\log N}$$ has a completely elementary proof. We are actually just saying *there aren't enough primes to ensure convergence* in a more accurate and quantitative form.

Comment: You can show that the convergence of $\sum_n \frac{\epsilon_n}{n} $ implies the convergence of $\lim_{s \to 1^-}\sum_n \frac{1}{n^s}  - 2\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s}  \sim \lim_{s \to 1^-} \zeta(s) - 2 \ln \zeta(s)\sim \frac{1}{s-1} + 2\ln (s-1) = -\infty$

Comment: @user1952009: that is a very valid argument, too.

Comment: And a much more elementary answer would be to show that $\pi(x) < x /2$ (for $x $ large enough)

Comment: @user1952009: I overlooked that, but you're clearly right.